# Graphical Plots of PDF and CDF

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a joint density and distribution function that I want to plot in a meaningful way, (i.e., want to be able to see how the functions behaves as changes in x and y happen simultaneously. If possible, I would like for the `x` axis to stay horizontal (left to right), and the `y` axis going into the screen. No particular choice is in mind at the moment such as (`Plot3D`, `ContourPlot3D`, or `DiscretePlot3D`). More than one way of plotting is encouraged just to see all useful possibilities of grasping useful information on how the functions behave. Maybe even an example including `Manipulate` would be very helpful as well. The functions are here below:

```
 (pdf)...    f[x_, y_] := x^2 y E^(-x (y + 1)) UnitStep[x] UnitStep[y]

 (cdf)...    F[x_, y_] := (1 - E^-x + ((y x + 1) E^(-x (y + 1)))/(y + 1) +
             (y E^(-x (y + 1)) - 2 y - 1)/(y + 1)^2) UnitStep[x] UnitStep[y]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best option, but in terms of graphics it would be interesting to plot and compare both continuous and discrete PDF's and CDF's, as well as contour plots.

Let me show what I usually do:

```
randomWalk[x_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
index = Table[randomWalk[10000], {2}];
asset[i_] := index[[i]];
pair1 = Transpose[{asset[1], asset[2]}];
```

Now the discrete bivariate histogram:

```
G1 = Histogram3D[pair1, {0.25}, "PDF", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Now the continuous bivariate plot:

```
G2 = Plot3D[Evaluate@PDF[BinormalDistribution[0/1],{x, y}],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

[image]

The countour plot:

```
G3 = ContourPlot[PDF[BinormalDistribution[0/1],{x,y}],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Plotting the CDF's. The discrete one:

```
G4 = Histogram3D[pair1, {0.25}, "CDF", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

The continuous one:

```
G5 = Plot3D[CDF[BinormalDistribution[1/2],{x, y}],{x,-4,4},{y,-4, 4},ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

[image]

And the CDF's contour plot:

```
G6 = ContourPlot[CDF[BinormalDistribution[1/2],{x,y}],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4},ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

[image]

P.S.: you can even mix the plots, showing them at the same time for comparison. You can try, for instance

```
Show[G1, G2]
```

[image]

```
Show[G4, G5]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Using your functions to plot the PDF, CDF and contour plots. Consider:

```
pdf[x_, y_] := x^2 y E^(-x (y + 1)) UnitStep[x] UnitStep[y];    
cdf[x_, y_] := (1 - E^-x + ((y x + 1) E^(-x (y + 1)))/(y + 1) + (y E^(-x (y + 1)) - 2 y - 1)/(y + 1)^2) UnitStep[x] UnitStep[y];
```

Now the plots:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@pdf[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

The PDF's contour plot:

```
ContourPlot[pdf[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

The CDF:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@cdf[x, y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 15},ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

And, finally, the CDF's contour plot:

```
ContourPlot[cdf[x, y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 15}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Marvelous.. Exactly what I was in need for and also can see clearly how they behave. Now these examples are just generic (correct?) just to be clear. So I could just replace this with my very own results for the pdf and cdf?

Comment: That's it! Just put your own data and voilá!

Comment: You can substitute `asset[1]` and `asset[2]` with your own data. This should work...

Comment: Not sure, I did the following: 

`randomWalk[x_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
index = Table[randomWalk[10000], {2}];
asset[i_] := index[[i]];
pair1 = Transpose[{f[x,y], F[x,y]}];`  It stated the transpose of f,F are not list of data sets.

Comment: You can't simply input your functions in the example I have provided... Furthermore what you've provided is a function, and, as such, can't be plotted as discrete data (i.e., you can't use the `Histogram3D` option). The only option you could use is `Plot3D`. In this case try to do this: `pdf[x_, y_] := x^2 y E^(-x (y + 1)) UnitStep[x] UnitStep[y];` and `Plot3D[Evaluate@pdf[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full, 
 Exclusions -> None]`.

Comment: If you want another view of your function, try this: `Plot3D[Evaluate@pdf[x, y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 15}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full, 
 Exclusions -> None]`

Comment: Don't forget to use the CDF. Set `cdf[x_,y_]:=(1 - E^-x + ((y x + 1) E^(-x (y + 1)))/(y + 1) + (y E^(-x (y + 1))-2y-1)/(y + 1)^2) UnitStep[x] UnitStep[y];` and then try `Plot3D[Evaluate@cdf[x, y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 15}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full, 
 Exclusions -> None]`.

Comment: Finally, `ContourPlot[cdf[x, y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 15}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`.

Comment: And `ContourPlot[pdf[x,y],{x,0,4},{y,0,6},ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]`.

Comment: Thank You! This was indeed helpful. Is there any non-drawn out way of getting the continuous functions as a data collection set to be able plot their histograms? I tried using a `Table` but it just gave a single solid block. If there is not then this should be just fine. I just liked how `Show` commands looked.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly... but I think you need to generate discrete data using your functions as parameters, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. But I'll just stick to the continuous plots, the histogram just looked neat. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

something quick to get you started.

```
DynamicModule[{xlim = 3, ylim = 3, xlimControl, ylimControl},

 xlimControl = 
  Row[{Text@"x limit", Spacer[5], 
    Manipulator[Dynamic[xlim, {xlim = #} &], {0.01, 5, 0.01}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny, ContinuousAction -> True], Spacer[5], 
    Dynamic[AccountingForm[xlim, {3, 2}, NumberSigns -> {"", ""}, 
      NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]]}];

 ylimControl = 
  Row[{Text@"y limit", Spacer[5], 
    Manipulator[Dynamic[ylim, {ylim = #} &], {0.01, 5, 0.01}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny, ContinuousAction -> True], Spacer[5], 
    Dynamic[AccountingForm[ylim, {3, 2}, NumberSigns -> {"", ""}, 
      NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]]}];

 Labeled[Grid[{

    {xlimControl},
    {ylimControl},

    {Dynamic[Grid[{{
         Plot3D[cdf[x, y], {x, -xlim, xlim}, {y, -ylim, ylim}, 
          AxesLabel -> {x, y, "cdf"}, Evaluate@commonPlotOptions, 
          PlotLabel -> "CDF"],
         Plot3D[pdf[x, y], {x, -xlim, xlim}, {y, -ylim, ylim}, 
          AxesLabel -> {x, y, "pdf"}, Evaluate@commonPlotOptions, 
          PlotLabel -> "PDF"]
         }}
       ]
      ]}
    }, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray], "version 3/9/13"],

 Initialization :>
  {
   commonPlotOptions = {PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> 20, 
     PerformanceGoal -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300, Mesh -> Full, 
     Exclusions -> None};
   pdf[x_, y_] := x^2 y E^(-x (y + 1)) UnitStep[x] UnitStep[y];

   cdf[x_, 
     y_] := (1 - 
       E^-x + ((y x + 1) E^(-x (y + 1)))/(y + 
          1) + (y E^(-x (y + 1)) - 2 y - 1)/(y + 1)^2) UnitStep[
      x] UnitStep[y];
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1.. Nice. Thanks for this. `:)`

Comment: Would it be much to create these to `DiscretePlot3D` graphs. I've tried, but I think there are some conflicting options in discretized rendering of graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest thing to do is to plot them using Plot3D

```
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
 Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Once plotted, you can grab them with the mouse and rotate to get the best viewing angle.
Or make it interactive to change between plotting styles

```
 Manipulate[GraphicsRow[{
    plot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> All],
    plot[F[x, y], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> All]}, 
 ImageSize -> 600], {plot, {Plot3D, ContourPlot, DensityPlot}}]
```

[image: different plotting commands]