# Visualizing a 2-dimensional PDF

Tags: plotting, visualization

I have empirical data that describes a 2-dimensional [Probability Density Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and I want to visualize that data in a meaningful way using Mathematica. My first instinct is to use a [2D Heat map style plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map), where high probabilities would be shown in red, and low in blue or white. However I am a novice when it comes to Mathematica's visualization power so I would like some community input. Is there a better way to visualize this data?

Comment: What is your data structure?

Comment: Have a look at [`PDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PDF.html). There are a couple of 2D examples.

Comment: Relevant: [How to combine ArrayPlots?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11247)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample of your data? (enough to play with)

Comment: @jens I feel the question is not "how to draw a heat map?", but "are there good alternatives to drawing a heat map?". So, this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20927/graphical-plots-of-pdf-and-cdf/20931#20931)?

Comment: @Rod Lm - I really like idea of using a 3D Historgram. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes, you are correct. I'm not looking for help on implementing a plotting routine, but instead help on understanding my options for visualizing my data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example using defined distributions:

```
Plot3D[PDF[BinormalDistribution[.3], {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> ColorData[45, 1], 
  PlotLabel -> "Multinormal", 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#3] &)]
```

[image]

or:

```
DensityPlot[
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[.3], {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Multinormal", ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

[image]

However, with empirical data, you can apply an empirical distribution.

Let's start with some *(not very)* empirical data:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.3], {2000}];
```

Now, we can apply a `SmoothKernelDistibution`. This will smooth your data. If the population of your samples isn't very large, its smoothing can overwhelm the data--so use some caution.

```
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
```

Now, we can plot it as above:

```
Plot3D[PDF[d, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Empirical Distribution", 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Other methods include fitting an assumed distribution, e.g. by using `EstimatedDistribution`, `FindDistributionParameters` or related.

Comment: Note OP is talking about "empirical data", not given functions.

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov, Yeah, probably should add something about that....

Comment: If one just wants to do visualization, instead of going through `SmoothKernelDistribution[]`, one could directly use `SmoothHistogram3D[]` or `SmoothDensityHistogram[]`.